# how to make output an input in python

Tags: python

```
>>> import math

#defining first function
>>> def f(a):
        return a-math.sin(a)-math.pi/2

#defining second fuction
>>> def df(a):
        return 1-math.cos(a)

#defining third function which uses above functions
>>> def alpha(a):
        return a-f(a)/df(a)
```

How to write a code in which alpha(a) takes a starting value of a=2, and the solution of alpha(2) will become the input the next time. For eg: let's suppose alpha(2) comes to 2.39 , hence the next value would be alpha(2.39) and go on {upto 50 iterations}. Can somebody please help me a bit. thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking to do this while the program is running, or are you looking to be able to quit the application and continue with the last used number?

Comment: Use a for-loop?

Comment: @idjaw while the program is running.Thanks

Comment: yes, thanks i will try using for-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let the program **iterate with a `for` loop**, and **use a variable to store the intermediate results**:

```
temp = 2                # set temp to the initial value
for _ in range(50):     # a for loop that will iterate 50 times
    temp = alpha(temp)  # call alpha with the result in temp
                        # and store the result back in temp
    print(temp)         # print the result (optional)
```

`print(temp)` will print the intermediate results. It is not required. It only demonstrates how the `temp` variable is updated throughout the process.

Comment: So, at some point the values keep repeating .Is there any program to choose the repeating value out of the 50 iteration??

Comment: @GarrySaini: usually if they start repeating, you can pick the last value. That means that you have found a *fixed point* of the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can objectify it.

```
import math

class inout:
    def __init__(self, start):
        self.value = start
    def f(self, a):
        return a-math.sin(a)-math.pi/2
    def df(self, a):
        return 1-math.cos(a)
    def alpha(self):
        self.value = self.value-self.f(self.value)/self.df(self.value)
        return self.value
```

Then create an `inout` object and each time you call its `alpha` method it will give the next value in the series.

```
demo = inout(2)
print(demo.alpha())
```